# Length vs Precision

Tags: sql-server

When I describe a table with `nvarchar` data type, what's the difference between `Precision` and `Length`? I see that `Length` is always the double. For example the values is `nvarchar(64)`, the precision is 64 and the length is 128.

```
CREATE TABLE T(X nvarchar(64))
EXEC sp_columns 'T'
```

Comment: "Precision" is associated with `decimal`, not `varchar()` (or `nvarchar()`).

Comment: Where are you looking to see these values? Generally, Precision (and Scale) only have a meaning for numeric types.

Comment: Are you confusing `Size` with `Length` in SQL Server management studio?

Comment: Never confuse size with length, and remember size isnt everything

Comment: maybe I explained wrong, if I need to go and check the data type of one nvarchar column to create a dynamic table, is Precision column that shows me the right information, I'm using sp_columns

Comment: Well also the text in your question said `6` not `64` which didn't help.

Comment: `sp_columns` is for use by ODBC applications only. You should use the system tables to get detailed schema information and avoid confusions

Answer (score 7):

Precision has no meaning for text data.

As for the Length property, I think you confuse it with the `Size` reported by SQL Server Management Studio, which is the size of a column in bytes. The `Length` of an `nvarchar(64)` column is 64 while `Size` is 128.

The size of unicode types (nchar, nvarchar) is double the number of characters because Unicode uses two bytes for each character.

You can get these values using the [LEN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx) function to get the number of characters and the [DATALENGTH](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486.aspx) function to get the number of bytes, eg.

```
select len(N'some value'), datalength(N'some value')
```

which returns `10  20`

**EDIT**

From your comments I see you use [sp_columns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176077.aspx) to get at the table's schema info. You shouldn't use any of the catalog stored procedures and use the catalog views instead.

As the documentation states, [catalog stored procedures](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182764.aspx) are used to support ODBC applications, hence their results are limited and may need interpretation, as you found out. `sp_columns` doesn't differentiate between character and data length for example.

Schema views like those in the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx) or [sys](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174365.aspx) schemas return detailed and unambiguous information. For example, [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188348.aspx) returns the character lnegth in `CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH` and byte size in `CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH`. It also includes collation and character set information not returned by `sp_columns`.

The `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views are defined by ISO so they don't include some SQL Server-specific info like whether a column is a computed columns, stored in a filestream or replicated. You can get this info using the [system object catalog views](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189783.aspx) like [sys.columns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176106.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

NVARCHAR doesnt have precision. Precision is used for decimal. And length is the character length.

> **nvarchar [ ( n | max ) ]**
>
> Variable-length Unicode string data. n defines the string length and can be a value from 1 through 4,000. max
>   indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes (2 GB). The
>   storage size, in bytes, is two times the actual length of data entered
>   + 2 bytes. The ISO synonyms for nvarchar are national char varying and national character varying.

From the [source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx):-

> Precision is the number of digits in a number.
>
> Length for a numeric data type is the number of bytes that are used to
>   store the number. Length for a character string or Unicode data type
>   is the number of characters

Comment: The question is about the text types, not the dumeric types

Comment: I still don't undestand, for example I have a column "Name nvarchar(10)", this means that I can't put a name greater than 10 characters, If I do in Management Studio a describe of the table for that column, I see in the precision column the value 10 which is actually the value that I'm looking for. I don't care about the length because when I need to create a table dynamically, the correct value is in precision column. Am I right? thanks

Comment: nvarchar means unicode variable characters. it allocates memory as same as varchar. But It stores unicode characters.  If you specify nvarchar(10) at the time of declaration then it allocates 0 memory location at the starting if you specify, it can be null. When you store 5 characters word it will allocate memory for 10 characters and store into that. So there will be no memory loss.

Comment: I would also recommend you to read this:- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx

Comment: I undestand that, I can see the difference now, but precision has the real value that I need to validate something dynamically right?

Comment: @rgx71 - What does "do in Management Studio a describe of the table for that column" mean? I'm not sure where you are even seeing this.

Comment: @rgx71:- I am not getting your point why you are looking for precision in a ncarchar???

Comment: @rgx71:- Precision has got no meaning for text data. It is used only for decimal numbers.!!!!

Comment: @rgx71:- Does that clear your doubt or still have something left?? :)

Comment: NO, I'm using sp_columns, the value that I need is in Precision column, for example if I have a nvarchar(10) column, the Precision column has a value of 10 and length has a value of 20. Now if I need to dynamically, create a temp table based on that column and I need to get the datatype, I can use type_name column to get the data type and precision column to get the value 10, is that ok?

Answer (score 0):

`NVARCHAR` doesn't have `precision`, and the `length` would be the character length.  Try the following SQL

```
SELECT LEN('Whats the length of this string?')
```

You may be confucing this with a `Numeric` or `Decimal`, see the [chart here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

3 Years later but still relevant.. had a similar issue;

I encountered a UDDT 'd_style', using alt+f1 I see this is a 'nvarchar, length=2, prec=1'.

And indeed, I cannot insert e.g. 'EU' in this field, as data would be truncated.
So length 2 does not mean 2 characters here. This is because each character is saved as 2 bytes, thus prec = length/2.

In this case, 'precision' is indeed the maximum amount of characters allowed.

However, when you create a new table with the 'nvarchar' datatype, you can simply enter the desired length (e.g. my_field nvarchar(2)) if you want to be able to insert example value 'EU'.

Mind that this is all quite 'practical', in theory, precision is only applicable for numeric values, and is the number of digits in a number. So we shouldn't be talking about a 'precision' for nvarchar.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, this is a confusing topic in SQL server, even the documentation is inconsistent.

For example see the syntax definition of [CREATE TABLE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx)

```
<data type> ::=   
[ type_schema_name . ] type_name   
    [ ( precision [ , scale ] | max |   
        [ { CONTENT | DOCUMENT } ] xml_schema_collection ) ]
```

You see "precision", but don't see "length | precision".
And as others pointed out, everywhere else in the documentation, they refer to the same attribute as length, when talking about character datatypes. Except where they don't, like the documentation of [sp_help](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187335.aspx) and companion.

```
Length  int     Column length in bytes.
Prec    char(5) Column precision.
Scale   char(5) Column scale.
```

Here length is the *storage* length. (Most people would call it size.)

So unfortunately there is no correct or final answer to your question, you must always consider the context, and consult the documentation, when in doubt.